# Elastic search Match Pharse Prefix not working exactly for different data

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic search, i am using match_phrase_prefix to search data,
it is not working as expected,

```
  {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
        "title": {
          "query": "microso"
        }
      }
    }
```

Above sample returning all results with title Microsoft,
but for below query data is empty.

```
  {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
        "title": {
          "query": "micro"
        }
      }
    }
```

If prefix search word length is 50% then results are coming.
Please suggest how to fix it.

[Mapping screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj638.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your mapping and the source of the document you are trying to query? We can't help you without that piece of information.

Comment: @PierreMallet mapping screen shot updated, please check

Comment: ok, no screen shot please, post your mapping in the question directly, and as you seems to use a custom analyzer can you share the configuration of this analyzer? We need to be able to reproduce if you want us to help you.

Comment: "ic-title-analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "english_possessive_stemmer-filter",
                "ic-english-stemmer-filter",
                "en_US-filter"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }

@PierreMallet this is analyser settings I think.

Comment: ok, can you add all the relevant part of your setting? We miss the definition of "english_possessive_stemmer-filter", "ic-english-stemmer-filter", "en_US-filter" . You can edit your question to add it to the body of your question instead of in a comment. I will be more readable :).